# Regex to extract all strings from source code used when calling a function

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

We have an old, grown project with thousands of php files and need to clean it up.

Throughout the whole project we do have a lot of function calls similar to:

```
trans('somestring1');
trans("SomeString2");
trans('more_string',$somevar);
trans("anotherstring4",$somevar);
trans($tx_key);
trans($anotherKey,$somevar);
```

All of those are embedded into the code and represent translation keys. I would like to find a way to extract all "translation keys" in all occurrences.

The PHP project is in VS Code, so a RegEx Search would be helpful to list the results. 
Or I could search through the project with any other tool you would recommend

However I would also need to "export" just the strings to a textfile or similar.

The ideal result would be:

```
somestring1
SomeString2
more_string
anotherstring4
$tx_key
$anotherKey
```

As a bonus - if someone knows, how I could get the above list including filename where the result has been found - that would be really fantastic!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
The RegEx I came up with:

```
/(trans)+\([^\)]*\)(\.[^\)]*\))?/gim
```

list the full occurrence - How can I just get the first part of the result (between Single Quotes OR between Double Quotes OR beginning with $)
See here: [regexr.com/548d4](http://regexr.com/548d4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ops - i forgot to add my RegEx Example ... Question has been updated.

Comment: Try `^(?:.*(trans\([^()]*\)(?:\.[^()]*\))?).*|.*\n?)` and replace with `$1`, see https://regex101.com/r/r8Zvz7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps to get exactly what you want.  Using this you can do a find and replace on your search results!

So you could do sequential regex find/replaces in the right circumstances. 
 The replace can be just within the search results editor and not affect the underlying files at all - which is what you want.

You can also have the replace action actually edit the underlying files if you wish.

*[Hint: This technique can also make doing a find item `a` / replace with `b` in files that contain term `c` much easier to do.]*

(1)  Open a new search editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
     (That command is currently unbound to a keybinding.)

(2)  Paste this regex into the Search input box (with the regex option `.*` selected):

```
     `(.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]+)(.*)`  - a relatively simple regex
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vquEVy/2)

---

See my other answer for a regex to work with up to 6 entries per line:

```
(\s*\d+:\s)?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*)((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?)(.*)
```

---

(3)  You will get a list of files with the search results.  Now open a Find widget <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in this Search editor.

(4)  Put the same regex into that Find input.  Regex option selected.  Put `$3` into the Replace field.  This only replaces in this Search editor - **not the original files** (although that can be done if you want it in some case).  `Replace All`.

---

If using the 1-6 version regex, replace with:

```
$1$5  $9  $13  $17  $21  $25
```

---

(5)  Voila.  You can now save this Search Editor as a file.

[image: Search Editor Find]

---

Comment: thanks for the tipps - almost there :)

How can I handle multiple results per line - ideally those would be listed as single entires, one per line. Please see updated https://regex101.com/r/vquEVy/3 demo

Comment: My regex-foo is not that good.  There is probably an easy way to capture as many entries per line as you have.  I'll present a way to capture 1 or 2 `trans(...)` per line but I can't figure out the regex for an unlimited number.  What is the most you have on a single line?

Comment: That changes the regex significantly (and should have been in your original question ;>}), especially if there might be other unwanted code before, between or after the `tran`'s.  I suggest asking another question with that info to try to get the regex.  That could then be applied here.  The regex needs to capture all the other code too for either of the two methods I showed to work - otherwise that other code is left behind in the final result which you probably don't want.

Comment: So I will mark this question as answered and will create another one later - thanks for your help anyway - very appreciated... in the meantime I will add a linebreak befora all "trans" and so should be able to reolve my problem. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Thanks, I modified the regex in the snippet version to make it work for 1-6 entries.  But not for 7+ `trans(..)` on one line.  I guess I'll modify the accepted answer too for the more complicated regex find/replace.  Do you mind if I edit your question/title to make it more likely that this editing of Search Editor results is possible and quite useful in certain case?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer works for one desired capture per line as in the original question.  But that relatively simple regex won't work if there are two or more per line.

The regex below works for up to 6 entries per line, like

```
trans('somestring1');
stuff trans("SomeString2"); some content trans("SomeString2a");more stuff [repeat, repeat]
```

But it doesn't for 7+ - you'll **need a regex guru** for that.

Here is the process again with a twist of **using a snippet in the Search Editor** instead of a Find/Replace.  Using a snippet allows more control over the formatting of the final result.

(1) Open a new search editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (That command is currently unbound to a keybinding.)

(2) Paste this regex into the Search input box (with the regex option .* selected):

```
 `((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*)((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?((.*?)(\btrans\(['"]?)([^,'")]*))?)(.*)`
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zilPT8/7)

(3) You will get a list of files with the search results. Now select all your results individually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

(4) Trigger this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",                              // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
  "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*)((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*))?((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*))?((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*))?((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*))?((.*?)(\\btrans\\([\\'\\\"]?)([^,\\'\\\")]*))?)(.*)/$4${8:+\n      }$8${12:+\n      }$12${16:+\n      }$16${20:+\n      }$20${24:+\n      }$24/g}"

  }
},
```

That snippet will be applied to each selection in your search result.  This part `${8:+\n      }` is a conditional which adds a newline and some spaces if there is a capture group 8 - which would be a second `trans(...)` on a line.

Demo: (unfortunately, it doesn't properly show the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> selecting all lines individually or the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> snippet trigger)

[image: Search Editor with a snippet transform]